# Google-Appengine asks me daily to "verify you are human"

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, captcha

I'm using Google AppEngine and pretty much daily my account get's requested to "verify you are a human. Then try again". Is there any way to prevent this from happening, or determine why this is occurs every day? I've looked at my Google Apps settings, my account settings, and I can't see any reason why I'm requested to validate daily.

The error that I get when trying to run appcfg.py commands is:

```
Please go to
https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
and verify you are a human.  Then try again.
Error 401: --- begin server output ---
Must authenticate first.
--- end server output ---
```

Is there anywhere I can check what triggers this captcha confirmation? And is there a way for me to disable the constant request to authenticate?

This happens on average once a day.

Comment: Are you behind a NAT with a number of other people who also use GAE?

Comment: I've never had that happen before so I really don't know what to suggest. =/ Is your gmail account phone verified?

Comment: BlindingDawn: It's a Turing problem. Amber: Yes, I'm behind NAT. Kort: It's a google-apps account, so no, did not have to phone verify.

Answer (score 0):

I get this occasionally across Google's services. They seem to have code that tries to pick up bots doing things they shouldn't, and asks you to confirm you're not a bot.

I'm sure Google will never tell us the factors they're using to decide this, but it could include things like IP address, user agent, speed of requests, etc.

I'd recommend posting it in the [App Engine Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine), since Google staff frequently stop by, and can probably flag it to be looged at.

Comment: I actually [have asked](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/7433dc52a8a6922d?pli=1) on the appengine group. If this only happened once in a while it might be ok, but daily is a serious problem.